# Receiving Swearing words as "Answer" (Not "cool")

Tags: discussion, support, etiquette

Please, I do not want to see or read any swearing words from the users or anyone on the Stack Exchange. I do not need to read them also. I have responsibilities to follow or catch up if needed. Could you please, try to prevent these things as much as possible!... **Thanks.** (I am leaving this one as just before...)

Comment: We cannot really *prevent* this from happening...

Comment: Could you please notice them about adding  more unwanted words or expanding the "black-list", at least!... I'm SURE that it IS POSSIBLE. Just try to have a look at my recent session history!...

Comment: I have a similar issue with people using all caps and bold on MSE...

Comment: @TheChaz: Sorry being such a pain, guys, but, please, try to understand being an adult. Thank you very much for your attention by the way...

Comment: Being an adult also implies dealing with problems like this gracefully. Bold all-caps text is, by internet standards, pretty ungraceful... That was The Chaz's point, Kerim.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Yes, sure, you are right about that. Let me do correct it now... And, please, make them their own job by the way... I am not thier boss, teacher or parents. Thank you so much for your patience...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have suspended the relevant user for a week.

Please let the moderators know using a flag (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work)) if any further issues occur.

Comment: Thanks, Zev. I'm almost sure that you can understand me...